# react-native log-android adb invocation failed

Tags: android, react-native

currently I'm having problem on do logging in react native.
I tried command : '**react-native log-android**' but shows error 
**adb invocation failed. Do you have adb in your PATH?**
I've research for the answer but still some link didn't find me any solution.

Here's the full log guys

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\wamp\www\ProjectAwesome\node_modules (49ms)
Starting the logger (c:\Users\gr351\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V)...
adb invocation failed. Do you have adb in your PATH?
(node:7696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:7696) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:7696) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in ADB PATH, usage of "\" "/" ,  You have given

```
c:\Users\gr351\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

But It should be

```
c:\Users\gr351\AppData\Local\Android**\Sdk\platform-tools\adb**
```

Comment: Hi @lib4 can you explain how do I achieve that?

Do you mean I should change my System Variables Path or something?

Comment: Yes in system variable you should change.  You can check whether adb is properly configured or not by just typing adb and press enter from command line. If the path is proper then it will display adb option. else it will show you "No such file or directory"

Comment: Just correcting my ADB Path in my System Variables and it does work! Thank you @lib4 ! :)